# Can I keep a marker whose owner I can't find?

Tags: halal-haram

One of a seminar speakers in our university,  gave me a marker and told me an office at some place and asked me to return it to them.

When I looked for that place, I could not find it.

**What should I do with that marker now?**

Answer (score -1):

salam.you should have asked others to help you find that office and at last if you really couldn't find that office then you should return that marker to the person who gave you that marker saying politely  that you were unable to find that office.

Comment: That person is unavailable, that office is not in that place according to my search and others' search but there is office of same name at the another edge of my university which doesn't seem the same office as he said.